# responsive iframe where the height adjusts when the the window is reduced in width

Tags: jquery, iframe

I cannot find any solution that will allow an iframe to contain a responsive page and the height to adjust automatically when the page is reduced in width(it cuts off the bottom content)

Is there a way I can implement this?